# Truncating text with ellipsis using CSS in Vue.js doesn't work

Tags: css, vue.js, truncate, ellipsis

I am working with a `component` which would render two `<li>` item, in which the following structure is displayed. I need to truncate the item text on small screens (for mobile mainly):

```
 <navigation-item>
    <span class="navigation-item__link_text">
      {{ $t('navigation.content') }}
    </span>
    <span
      class="navigation-item__link-count">{{ contentCount }}
    </span>
  </navigation-item>
```

**NavigationItem.vue** is as follows:

```
<template>
<router-link
  :to="`/${page}/`"
  class="navigation-item"
  tag="li">
 <a class="navigation-item__link" tabindex="0">
  <slot />
 </a>
</router-link>
</template>
```

I have used the following `CSS`:

```
.navigation-item__link_text {
 width:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

But the truncation doesn't work at all. What could I be doing things wrong?

Comment: Your `navigation-item__link_text` block is to wide IMO, try removing `width:100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add following css to .navigation-item__link_text

```
width: 85%;
display: inline-block;
```

https://codepen.io/frantisekvrab/pen/GwXpoB